# Novel about immortality but it isn’t nice, people still age and decay

Tags: story-identification, novel, stephen-king, dean-koontz

I’m looking for a novel by either Stephen King or Dean Koontz. A central idea in the novel is that immortality exists but the immortal person still ages and decays like an ordinary mortal.

I think I read it in the late 80’s. It would have been recently published at that time. There was an extremely old woman who the lead character encounters on a road (I think). She may have been a gypsy and she may have cursed the lead character with immortality.

Anyway, turns out living forever might not be so good. You can’t die but you still age and decay.

Comment: I paged through https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AgeWithoutYouth, but nothing seemed to match that well.

Comment: There is a passage in *Gulliver's Travels* by Jonathan Swift much like that, when he hears of the immortal Struldbruggs. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struldbrugg

Comment: Stephen King's novel "Thinner" has the protagonist kill an old gypsy woman in a pedestrian/vehicle accident, then he encounters her extremely aged father who puts a curse on him. The aged father had a lesion on his face.